# service called two times

Tags: java, http

I am trying to call my HttpServer with a POST and send a message in the body, on the server side I can see that it is called twice and I cannot figure out why.
Here is a part of the client code

```
String URL = "http://localhost:8081/" + path  +"/service?session=" + sessionId; 
connection = openConnection(URL, "POST");
OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
output.write("Some Random body data".getBytes());
output.close();         
stream = connection.getInputStream();
stream.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

On the server side i can see that the service is called two times. I figure it has to do something with my OutputStream and InputStream, but if i dont call the input stream it wont call the service any time.

EDIT!!!
Here is some more code
    public class Server {

```
private static final int BASE_PORT = 8081;  

public static void main(String[] args) {                    
    try{
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(BASE_PORT);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(address, 0);
        server.createContext("/", new PathDelegator());
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server is listening on : " + BASE_PORT);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class PathDelegator implements HttpHandler{   
public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
    String URI =  exchange.getRequestURI().toString();  
    if(URI.indexOf("/session") != -1){                                  
        //Call ServiceHandler
        System.out.println("Call ServiceHandler");
        serviceHandler(exchange, "some session key");
    }               
}
private void serviceHandler(HttpExchange exchange, String sessionId) throws IOException{
    String requestMethod = exchange.getRequestMethod();
    OutputStream responseBody = exchange.getResponseBody();
    if(requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){         
        Headers responseHeaders = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");                  
        InputStream stream = exchange.getRequestBody();
        int b = 0;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((b = stream.read()) != -1){                   
            buffer.append((char)b);                 
        }
        System.out.println("body data: " + buffer.toString());
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);                                                                       
    }else {
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(400, 0);
    }
    responseBody.close();
}
```

}

```
public class ClientTest {
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToPostToService(){
    try {
        String SCORE_URL = "http://localhost:8081/service?session=" + sessionId;    

        connection = openConnection(URL, "POST");

        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write("Some body data".getBytes());
        output.close();

        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        stream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        fail("Not implemented yet!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private HttpURLConnection openConnection(String url, String method) throws IOException{
    URL connectionURL = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)connectionURL.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod(method);

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return connection;      
}
```

}

Finallty i see that the `System.out.println("body data: " + buffer.toString());` is outputted two times

Comment: How are you sure that service is called twice?

Comment: like i said, in the service i have a log that prints out the body data. And i will have something like this
"Some Random body data"
"Some Random body data"

Comment: Could you maybe post more of the code?  The entire method and possible the code that calls this method?  There doesn't seem anything TOO glaringly wrong with the current code.

Comment: added more code in the original post

Comment: Better than the code, can you add the network traffic captured with wireshark or tcpdump?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i finally figured out what was going on...
i had a method
    `public synchronized boolean addValue(int id, int value){
            Integer previous = values.put(id, value);
            return previous.intValue() != value;
        }`

problem was that the first time, the put would return a NULL value and as soon as i took care of this method the error does not occur no more.